# Метод для добавления объекта в массив объектов

Tags: java

Я получил задание от преподавателя создать классы  Peson и Contai. Класс Container должен хранить объекты класса Peson в виде массива(использовать коллекции запрещено).
Код класса  Container:

```
public class Container {

    /**Field size store size massiv.
 */
    private int size;

   private  Person [] mass = new Person[size];

    /**This is constructor.

 *
 * @author Data
     * @param size
 */
    public Container( int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

     /**Method setSize set size.
     * @param size
 */
    public final void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    /**Method getSize return size.
     * @return
 */
    public  final int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setMass(Person[] mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    public Person[] getMass() {
        return mass;
    }








    public  void add( Person obj)
    {


     //  DateTime   date = new DateTime(1965, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0);

       // Person p2 = new Person(1, "Petrov V.V", date, "man");
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)

        {
           if( mass[i]==null)
           {
               mass[i]=obj;
               break;
           }
           //new Person(i, "Petrov", date, "man");
        }


    }

    /**Method show(Person [] mass2) receive argument as
     * massiv objects of  class Person and show it elements.
     * @param mass2
 */
    public final void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Show elements massiv:");
        for(Person el:  mass) {
            System.out.println("Id:" + el.getId() + "\n" + "NFS:" + el.getNFS() + "\n" + "Date:" + el.getDate() + "\n" + "Sex:" + el.getSex() + "\n");
        }
    }

    /**Method getelement(Person [] mass2,int index) receive argument
     * as  massiv objects of  class Person and index element massiv and show element massiv.
     * @param mass2
     * @param index
 */
    public final void getelement(int index)
    {

        System.out.println("Get element for index:" + index);
            System.out.println("Id:" + mass[index].getId() + "\n"+
                    "NFS:" + mass[index].getNFS() + "\n" +
                    "Date:" + mass[index].getDate()+ "\n" + "Sex:" +
                    mass[index].getSex() + "\n");

    }
/**Method delete_element(int index) receive
 * index element massiv and delete this element.
     * @param index
 */
    public final void delete_element(int index)
    {

        Person[] mass2 = new Person[mass.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(mass, 0, mass2, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(mass, index + 1, mass2, index,
                mass.length - index - 1);
        System.out.println("Massiv without element with index:" + index);
       // show(mass2);
    }
}

Код класса  Person:
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;





import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import org.joda.time.Period;

/**Class Person contains four field:
 * 1) id as identifikator;
 * 2) NFS-Name Father Surname;
 * 3) date - date birthday
 * 4) sex - sex Person
 *
 * Methods getDate(),getSex(),getId(), getNFS() -returns values fields class
 * Methods setDate(),setSex(),setId(), setNFS() -set values fields class
 *
 * Method difference_date() -calcute age Person
 * @author Data
 */
public class Person {
    /**Filed "id" as identifikator.

 */
    private int id;

    /**Filed "NFS"-Name Father Surname.

 */
    private String NFS;


     /**Filed date - date birthday.

 */
    private DateTime date;

     /**Filed sex - sex Person.

 */
    private String sex;

    /**Method getDate() return date.
     * @return
 */

    public final DateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**Method getSex() return sex.
     * @return
 */
    public final String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    /**Method getId() return Id.
     * @return
 */
    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

     /**Method getNFS() return NFS.
     * @return
 */
    public final String getNFS() {
        return NFS;
    }


     /**Method setDate set field date.
     * @param date
 */
    public final void setDate(DateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**Method setId set field Id.
     * @param id
 */
    public final void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**Method setNFS set field NFS.
     * @param NFS
 */
    public final void setNFS(final String NFS) {
        this.NFS = NFS;
    }

    /**Method setSex set field sex.
     * @param sex
 */
    public final void setSex(final String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**This is constructor.
     * @param id
     * @param NFS
     * @param date
     * @param sex
 */
    public  Person(final int id, String NFS, DateTime date, String sex) {
        this.id = id;
        this.NFS = NFS;
        this.date = date;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**Method difference_date() calculate and print age Person.

 */
    public final void differenceDate()
    {

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();


    Period p = new Period(date, now);
    long hours = p.getHours();
    long minutes = p.getMinutes();
    long years = p.getYears();

    System.out.println("Age:" + years + "\n");

    }

}
```

Но когда в методе main главного класса Main  я добавляю объекты класса  Person и вызываю метод show, никакие элементы массива не выводятся.

Код метода main главного класса Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int size = 5;
        final int indexGet = 2;
        final int indexDelete = 0;
        final int year = 1965;
        final  int month = 7;
        final int day = 22;
        final int unit_time = 0;

       // System.out.println("Hello World");
     DateTime   date = new DateTime(year, month, day, unit_time,
             unit_time, unit_time, unit_time);
       Person p = new Person(0, "Petrov V.V", date, "man");
       p.differenceDate();
        Person p2 = new Person(1, "Petrov V.V", date, "man");

       Container c = new Container(size);
       c.add(p);
       c.add(p2);


      c.show();
       /*c.getelement(c.create_and_initialize(), indexGet);
       c.delete_element(indexDelete);*/
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с данной проблемой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос: чему в этом месте равен `size`?

```
private  Person [] mass = new Person[size];
```

Ответ: в этом месте `size` равен нулю.

---

```
private Person[] mass;
private int capacity;
private int count = 0;

public Container(int capacity) {
  this.capacity = capacity;
  mass = new Person[capacity];
}

public void add(Person obj) {
  if (count == capacity)
    throw new Exception("capacity exceeded");
  mass[count++] = obj;
}

public final void show()
{
  System.out.println("Show elements massiv:");
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Person el = mass[i];
    System.out.println("Id:" + el.getId() + "\n" + "NFS:" + el.getNFS() + "\n" + "Date:" + el.getDate() + "\n" + "Sex:" + el.getSex() + "\n");
  }
}
```